# removing dashboard menu options for the user role editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove some of the dashboard menu tabs on my wordpress site using this code:

```
//Remove some menu options
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
    $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Media'), __('Contact'), __('Links'), __('Pages'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Users'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'));
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

At the moment this removes the menus from all user roles, how could I update this to just apply to editors?

Ive also got this snippet of code but dont know how to combine it with what I have:

```
$editor = get_role('editor');
$editor->remove_cap('publish_pages');
```

Comment: If I recall, using remove_cap will also induce Wordpress to hide the pertinent menu items for you, but it may depend on your version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function remove_menus () {
    if(is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('editor'))
    {
        global $menu;
        $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Media'), __('Contact'), __('Links'), __('Pages'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Users'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'));
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```